# Mongo Collection Find By Id with Filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

To find one item from mongo collection, I am trying to apply filter and to the collection. But there is a compilation error as below.

[image]

This code is taken from official `mongodb` docs

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
var result = _collection.Find(filter);
```

Comment: Does your project have reference to MongoDB.Driver 2.0.X?

Comment: @rnofenko Yes, it's reference is 2.0.1.27

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generic Type of `Builder` should be the same as for collection's generic type. In your case collection should have type BsonDocument.

```
var _collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("name");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
var result = _collection.Find(filter);
```

Answer (score 6):

When the "_id" is a BsonType.ObjectId, you will need to use ObjectId.Parse like this:

```
var _collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("name");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
var result = _collection.Find(filter);
```